# Parse.com - query.equalTo() to match a bunch of pointers?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Can I use the query.equalTo() to match a bunch of pointers? Currently I have
`query.equalTo('columnName', anObject);`

I will have an array of `anObject`s to be added dynamically, can the `query.equalTo()` method handle that, or do I have to use another method?

Answer (score 0):

Parse object store in global variable at time you get the object id.
like me i want to get the current user object id.
so i do like when user login that time i store parse object id at comman class.
when i need that current user id that time i get it easy like .

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> getwishlit = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
            "sharing_master");
    getwishlit.addAscendingOrder(key_createdAt);
    getwishlit.whereEqualTo(key_ownby, CommanClass.ParseObject_USER);
    getwishlit.whereEqualTo(key_sharingclass, key_classwishlist);

    getwishlit.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                Log.e("in the Array List ", " :: ::  :" + list.size());
            } else {
                Log.e("in the Array List ",
                        " :: ::  : Error" + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
```

here CommanClass.ParseObject_USER is static variable at a user login that time i store parse object.
try this way is completed work for me.